# Converting a Range to display as a String

Tags: python-3.x

New python user here;

Write a program that reads a single line of text as input and outputs only the first, third, fifth... letter of the string.
I have trouble converting the range to display as a string

My Code:

---

```
 user = str(input("Please enter a string: "))
 for x in user:
    if range(0,user,2) :
        print(str(user))
```

Comment: You can also get the list by indexing the string directly: `print user[::2]`

Answer (score 1):

You can read input as string and use a loop that runs from 0 till length of the string, incremented by 2. Then you can print the value at each position.

You can find length of a string with `len()` like this

`length = len(string)`

Your code can be edited like shown below

```
user = str(input("Please enter a string: "))

for i in range(0, len(user), 2):
    print(user[i], end=' ')
```

**Output**

```
# Let input = abcdefghi

a c e g i
```

Hope this helps.!!